# Adding action to each step of a multistep form

Tags: forms

I'm trying to have a multistep form for user registration.
I'm trying the Flexiform module.
In the first step I ask for user mobile number, then using an action I want to send a random number to him.

In the second step I'll ask him for the random number so I can validate the mobile number.(I can have a default random value for a hidden field in the first step to be able to use it for the validation).

The question is: How I can actions to each step of the form?
In the rules actions, it seems I have only actions for submission of whole form.

Thanks in advance for any help.